# extjs4 javascripts with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, extjs

i have just started working with ext js 4...previously i was using ext js 3 & included following javascripts & css in xds_index.html..which javascripts & css am i supposed to include for extjs 4?? I cant view the UI components in browser :(

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.3.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyPanel.ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyPanel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xds_index.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 3):

The js files you are using are for 3.3.1. For Ext JS 4, all you need is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script src="../bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Below this, you can add all your custom js files.

Comment: do you have any js error? did you check if the files are loaded?

Comment: i m get following errors for ext-all-debug.js : "You Are using ServerProxy but have not supplied it with url" & Ext.ClassManager : Cannot create instance of unrecognized alias: widget.editorgrid

Comment: you have issue with your code and not the file inclusions! Check if your Proxy is configured correctly. Cannot help without looking into your code

Comment: FYI, the bootstrap is for dynamic loading, which is intended primarily for development. For deployment you will still want to use ext-all.js or your own custom build.

Answer (score 0):

Ext 4 is not backwards-compatible, and it sounds like you're trying to just drop it into existing 3.x code based on your errors, which will not work.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637457/upgrade-from-ext-js-3-x-to-ext-js-4-beta/5642212#5642212) for more info.